# Cannot Edit or View Post with Comments App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have built a simple Rails app that has posts with one/many comments.

I want to create a simple post view that allows me to view the post and associated comments. I want each comment to have links to - view, edit, delete.

However whenever I try amending the code below I get routing errors. Help?

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
   resources :comments
end
```

rake routes

```
 post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                   POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
  new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
 edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
 post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
              PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
              DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @post }
 end
end

def edit
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

comments\show.html.erb

```
 <p>
   <b>Commenter:</b>
   <%= @comment.user_id %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <b>Comment:</b>
   <%= @comment.text %>
 </p>

 <%= link_to 'View Comment', comment_path(?) %> |
 <%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_comment_path(?) %> |
 <%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [@post, comment],
        :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
        :method => :delete %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing:

*Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.*

I duplicated your project with the code you provided and only received that routing error because there wasn't an id being passed to the route helper methods.  Because these are restful routes, the format for View Comment should be /comments/:id(.:format).

I was able to resolve this error by passing an id or comment object to the comment_path and edit_comment_path helper methods like so:

```
<%= link_to 'View Comment', comment_path(2) %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_comment_path(3) %> |
<%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [@post, comment],
    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
    :method => :delete %></p>
```

Obviously you would want to populate them with the correct ids or comment objects rather than just some random id.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: How do I bring back the correct record, rather than a random number/record?

Comment: You are assigning the instance variable @comment with the current comment in the show action of the comments controller.  So when you are building those links on the show view, instead of passing in a random id to comment_path and edit_comment_path, pass in @comment.id
`<%= link_to 'View Comment', comment_path(@comment.id) %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_comment_path(@comment.id) %> |
<%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [@post, @comment],
    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
    :method => :delete %></p>`

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the problem :D